# Method override signature match warning - Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: python, pycharm, overriding, warnings, liskov-substitution-principle

I have the following code in PyCharm:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self, a):
        raise NotImplementedError
        

class Child(Parent):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(a):
        print(a)


class OtherChild(Parent):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(a, b=2):
        print(a, b)


class ThirdChild(Parent):
    def foo(self, a):
        print(self, a)
```

Pycharm gives me a warning for "Signature of method 'Child.foo()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'Parent'". But see no such warnings on `OtherChild.foo()` or `ThirdChild.foo()`.

I'm tyring to understand if I am see false positive or false negative warnings for signature matching.

I think that all three children are complian with the Liskov substitution principle because `Parent.foo()` has one required argument and each child method also has one required argument. I don't know if instance vs static method has any implications for Liskov substituion.

Basically I see two strange things here.

- If you compare `Child.foo()` and `OtherChild.foo()` you can see they are both static methods (whereas `Parent.foo()` is an instance method). `Child.foo()` gets the warning but `OtherChild.foo()` does not. Somehow adding the extra optional argument clears the signature matching warning. (adding a second required argument brings back the signature warning as I would expect based on LSP).
- Now, if you compare `Child.foo()` with `ThirdChild.foo()` we see they are both methods with one required argument, `a` but `Child.foo()` is static whereas `ThirdChild.foo()` is an instance method. `ThirdChild.foo()` does not get the warning.

So my questions are:

- Are all three of these classes indeed compliant with Liskov Substitution Principle? If not, why?
- Why do I only see the warning on `Child.foo()`? Is this expected behavior or is this actually a PyCharm bug that I should report in their bug tracking system?

One workaround is I can do

```
class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self, a):
        print(a)
```

This is the same as the code above but I've left off the `@staticmethod` decorator around `foo()`.  Normally this would give a `Method 'foo' may be static` warning, but in this case, I guess because the method is overriding a parent method, the warning is not present. This code gives no warnings.